# Get variable name of subroutine input

Tags: perl

Is there a way to get the variable name of the input to a subroutine? I want to do the following:

```
use MyModule;
my $x = 'test';
MyModule::print_var_name($x); # prints '$x'
```

Of course there are a lot of cases where this makes no sense, e.g. `print_var_name(1+2)`. Only the simple case is important to me.

My plan is to use this variable name as a sensible default value for a pretty-print function.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but there are modules out there that actually do this. For example, [Data::Dumper::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~ovid/Data-Dumper-Simple-0.11/lib/Data/Dumper/Simple.pm) uses source filters and [Data::Dumper::Names](http://search.cpan.org/~ovid/Data-Dumper-Names-0.03/lib/Data/Dumper/Names.pm) internally uses the fragile [PadWalker](http://search.cpan.org/~robin/PadWalker-1.98/PadWalker.pm).

Comment: You can solve your example by simply doing `print '$x'`. Why do you feel you need something different? Can you give a working example?

Comment: @Mohith; personally I'd consider PadWalker to be a much more reliable solution than source filters. If you take a look at the number of RT tickets open for Data::Dumper::Simple and Data::Dumper::Names, and also the CPAN testers pass/fail counts, I think you'll find these statistics agree with me.

Comment: just require them to pass the name.  that even lets them do e.g. `MyModule::print_var_name($x, 'x after assignment')`

Comment: @TLP E.g. a pretty-print function where `dump_var($x);` outputs `$x = { q => 56, a => 42 }`

Comment: @ysth Sure, I just want a more useful default value than "var". But it seems like source filters would be needed, so I suppose it isn't worth the hassle.

Comment: source filters or PadWalker::var_name, yes.  either has limitations.

Comment: @Anna While it is perhaps possible to get something like that, its often not the right thing to do. If you want storable data, use a proper serializer module. If you want human readable, just print the variable name + `Data::Dumper` output. You could for example use a hash and `Data::Dumper` to do that. `my %x = ( x => $x ); print Dumper \%x` gives `$VAR1 => { 'x' => { 'q' => 56, 'a' => 42 } }`. What you have here sounds like an XY-problem.

Comment: Instead of PadWalker::var_name you could use B to get the PADNAME of the first element in the PADNAMELIST.